# Cant debug react native using VSCode android emulator is not launching debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

React-Native-Tools extension is installed.

there is only 1 file in .vscode directory its launch.json.I am working on this for hours but couldnt run debugger.When i press debug after chosing Debug android i get debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly error.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

another problem is after typing npm start eventhough my phone is connected to pc i cant start it on android by pressing a(my pc is configuered for debugging since i can debug using android studio)
[image]

Comment: did you configure android studio already?? properly plus enable usb debugging mode in your phone you need to open a developer option menu

Comment: what do you mean configure android studio ? i am already developing native android using android studio and debuggin using my phone

Comment: did you try following these instruction properly? I remember on react-native adb does not automatically run https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: i can see my phone with adb devices. react-native run-android  outputs :Scanning folders for symlinks in C:..projnodedir (66ms)   and nothing happens

Comment: How did you resolve this?